# Windows 8 screen resolution on a acer aspire one 1366x768

Tags: windows, installation, resolution, acer-aspire

I have just installed windows 8 on my acer aspire netbook, I made sure I had the required resolution of 1366x768.  Once installed I can not get 1024x768, I tried downloading and installing the win 7 driver but the widgets are all fuzzy, anything I can do to sort this?

Many thanks

Comment: to be clear, is your current resolution 1024x768 and you want 1366x768? or is it that you cannot downsize it to 1024x768? also, what graphics or laptop model you have?

Comment: Laptop model is AO751h, current resolution is 1024x768 and I would like 1366x768 to get the fully featured windows 8, many thanks

Comment: Well that laptop does indeed have a [native resolution of 1366x768](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834115579), but it seems that getting that resolution can be a [challenge](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne/AO751h) [sometimes](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=16284). My guess would be that you need to update the graphics drivers. As Andy said, you may need to check with Acer’s site to get the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 requires a minimum resolution of 1366x768.  The extra width is to support the snapping of a metro style application to the left or right of the screen.  I'd go back to the Windows 8 driver and put the resolution at 1366x768.

I would download the latest video drivers for your laptop here: http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=1&modelId=1112

The Windows 7 drivers should work fine in Windows 8.

If that doesn't work you can rollback the driver.  This is built into Windows, and while these instructions are for Windows 7 you can do the same in Windows 8 (http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/roll-back-driver-windows-7.htm).

Open your Charms menu and click Search.  Type 'Device Manager' and click on Settings in the Search charm fly out.  Open Device Manager, expand Display Adapters.  You should see your video card.  Right click on it and on the properties page that opens click on the Driver tab.  On this tab you should see a button to Roll Back Driver.

Comment: I originally had 1366x768 in vista, but on installation of windows 8 I only have 1024 with no other option available.  I tried the windows 7 driver but the tiles were all fuzzy, so I reverted back, any ideas on how to make them not fuzzy?

Comment: @Lee I added to my answer.

Comment: Andy thanks for the update.  I did exactly what you said above and reverted back as the tiles were fuzzy, don't know what to try next?

Comment: @Lee can you change the resolution now?  You may have to completely uninstall and re-install your drivers.

Comment: Andy, not sure how I uninstall the original driver?  Surely if I install the win 7 driver again, I will just get the same result?

Comment: Andy, I tried installing again but got the same result on the tiles screen, if only I could show you the screen!

Comment: @lee, you somehow need to get the right drivers back, and then you should be able to switch your resolution to the 1366x768 mode.  I'm not sure there's much else I can do at this point.  Have you tried contacting Acer for support?

Comment: Andy, I never had the correct drivers, I am trying to find one, that's why I have been on this forum, it looks as if Acer are not supporting it so really I need a work around.  I appreciate all you have said, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this working in Windows 8.0 with some drivers which I no longer have when I updated my OS to 8.1. Now its impossible to get native resolution on win 8.1 with this laptop.

I tried installing the Intel 500 drivers for Win7 (`VGA_Intel_v.8.14.10.2003_Win7x86`), but a lot of items are totally unreadable due to video corruption. Win 8.1 seems to be using real time VFX processing that this card cannot handle. So, basically I reverted to the default drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought an `Acer Aspire E5 571G 56FL` and installed `Windows 8.1`. Everything on my screen just appears larger and magnified. When I go to Display then "Screen Resolution" it says:

```
" Display: 1. Mobile PC Display
Resolution: 1366 x 768 (Recommended) (which I have it set to in the corresponding drop down menu)
Warning! Your resolution is lower than 1280 x 900. Some items might not fit on your screen.

Orientation: Landscape "
```

**I Tried**:
Uninstalling both VGA drivers and reinstalling again; but did not work

**Solution That worked for me**:
I was given a DVD of drivers with the Laptop

[image]

I installed `I/O driver I2C`

[image]

then restarted the computer. Then It the resolution was fine.

If not working you can try re-installing VGA drivers

**Ultimate SOlution**:
Try installing all the softwares/drivers in the application from DVD shown above